# How I can send message using telegram bot with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, telegram

I want to build a script that can send me a message via bot telegram if the element on the page is nonexistent. I've tried this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import telegram

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://site123123.ma")
#login
username_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_email"]')
username_box.send_keys('email')
password_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_password"]')
password_box.send_keys('Password')
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="new_user"]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
submit_button.click()
time.sleep(7)
#check the element if non exist send me message via bot telegram : help me here
#if the element is exist try every 1 min until the elemnt is non exist : help me here
notice=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="subs-content"]/p') 
#my token
bot=telegram.Bot('14XXXXX751:AAEY-XXXXXX-70ADVkuHawry-GO28Fk')
#my chat id :help me here
bot.send_message('9XXXXXX13', 'The POOL is ready You can Now take your place Fast')
```

My code misses a lot of things, just see the comment in the code.

Comment: #check the element if non exist send me message via bot telegram : help me here
#if the element is exist try every 1 min until the elemnt is non exist : help me here  - we need to see HTML code, share in text format

Comment: this is the text in the page : Aucune piscine n'est actuellement disponible and this is location by xpath '//*[@id="subs-content"]/p'  simply i want to check this element over and over until non exist and i want the bot telegram send me a message if the text 'Aucune piscine n'est actuellement disponible ' is non exist this is mean for me that the site is publish the date to take my place

Comment: HTML : https://imgur.com/SFBPw8O

Comment: page look : https://imgur.com/olluiuE

Answer (score 0):

step1: search botfather on telegram, make a simple bot and copy the bot token, reference: [https://medium.com/@ManHay_Hong/how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-and-send-messages-with-python-4cf314d9fa3e](http://create_bot%20medium%20artiicle)

step2: add the bot to the channel where you want to send a notification

step3: hit `https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR TOKEN>/getUpdates` u will get chat_id of the respective channel

step4: use this code

```
import requests
bot_token = ''
bot_chatID = ''
bot_message = 'test'
send_api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
response = requests.get(send_api)
```

Comment: your code super helpful i already has my token and my chat id please see my comment that's in my code :)  #check the element if non exist send me message via bot telegram : help me here
#if the element is exist try every 1 min until the elemnt is non exist : help me here
notice=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="subs-content"]/p')

Comment: please i want to add a fonction if the element is disable then send me message , can you show me how i can do this by exmple code